# Visual studio 2015 - How to change default currency?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, currency

So, I'm working on a simple program to display a quantity as currency, but it is displayed as euros, I would like it to be displayed as dollars.

I have read that it may be because of the region or something related, but I´m in Mexico, I don´t know why it would be displayed as euros if what I read is true.

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Is it hosted somewhere?  Perhaps your host server is in a region that uses Euros.

Comment: This is not Visual Studio related.  It's .net Culture related.  Also, please show your code.

Comment: Specify the culture in the call to `Format`
    `decimal value = 123.45M;`
    `CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");`
    `string s = string.Format(us, "{0:C}", value);`

Comment: It's not hosted anywhere... The code is pretty simple:                        label1.Text = Decimal.Parse(txtBox1.Text).ToString("C");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `CultureInfo` that your app is running under.

You can change the current thread, based on a language-culture combination. Just do the following:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

If you're looking for more granular control, you can create a `CultureInfo` and specify when formatting strings.

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"); 
var formattedVal = string.Format(currentCulture , "{0:C}", 12500.55);
```

Comment: I tried the second one and it worked, but I was wondering if I'm going to have to do that every time I create a new project?  Or is there a way of modifying an option in visual studio that applies this change permanently?

Comment: Are you trying to set one value or is it for your entire app? The `CultureInfo` is initially set by what the system culture is.

Comment: It would be for the entire app.

Comment: You would want to use the first snippet, setting it sometime soon after the app starts, such as `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax` (presuming you're working in asp.net)

Comment: For multiple projects, ensure that Windows is set to the culture you want to be working in.